# Using WriteableBitmapEx

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-metro, writeablebitmapex

I am currently developing metro apps and I need to write text On images.

I found this http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

But I am new to XAML and dosent know how to use it specifically.
So can anyone say me how do I use it in order to write text on image.

As I have asked this question on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/c518054e-1801-497b-b322-1c1a5b9d7777) but I have no reply yet.

*Edit:*

If I use as **Muad'Dib** I am getting the error as seen in below screenshot:

[image]

The **Error** is: `'Writeable Bitmap Extensions' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging'`

Comment: the WriteableBitmapEx library is also on NuGet

Answer (score 0):

there is one possible solution in the [Discussions area for WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/discussions/211173?ProjectName=writeablebitmapex)

here is the code from that "article":

```
 public static void DrawText(this WriteableBitmap wBmp,Point at, string text,double fontSize,Color textColor)
    {        
        TextBlock lbl = new TextBlock();
        lbl.Text = text;
        lbl.FontSize = fontSize;
        lbl.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(textColor);
        WriteableBitmap tBmp = new WriteableBitmap(lbl, null);
        wBmp.Blit(at, tBmp, new Rect(0, 0, tBmp.PixelWidth, tBmp.PixelHeight), Colors.White, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmapExtensions.BlendMode.Alpha);
    }
```

Comment: @Muad-Recently I have posted on the discussion about this and I am getting error as updated.

Comment: The code I posted from the discussion is in C#, I see in your image that you are using VB. I don't know VB, I'm not going to be much help here.